# How do I install a Java plugin for Google Chrome?

Tags: java, google-chrome

I'm a Java developer so I have the Java 7 JDK installed on my computer from Oracle (Sun). This obviously comes with the JRE. However, Google Chrome says I need the java plugin and wants me to install a JRE. Why is it not recognizing the one I already have?

Answer (score 1):

http://www.iasptk.com/ubuntu-oracle-java7-jdk7-jre7-firefox-chrome-plugin

**Ubuntu. Oracle Java 7. Install the Firefox/Chrome Oracle Java 7 plugin**

In a terminal:

```
mkdir ~/.mozilla/plugins
```

Remove the IcedTea plugin, if it has been installed.

```
sudo apt-get remove icedtea6-plugin
```

Remove a former version of the Java plugin (may or may not be present)

```
sudo rm ~/.mozilla/plugins/libnpjp2.so
```

Now you can install the plugin, by creating a symbolic link (you tell Firefox, where the plugin is located).

```
sudo ln -s /usr/lib/jvm/jre1.7.0_09/lib/i386/libnpjp2.so ~/.mozilla/plugins/
```